# SwiftUI accessibilityScrollAction not accepting rectangle edge as valid?

Tags: swiftui

So I'm trying to make an accessible game using SwiftUI, and it would be awesome to have a custom scroll action for blind users so that they don't have to swipe items using an extra set of gestures.

I'm trying to implement the scroll action on a view, but so far I've had no luck.

I have tried setting the edge to something like `.leading`, but it says that type Edge has no member leading. I also tried putting a `.` and letting it auto complete (nothing), and reading the documentation, which also gives me nothing, except that things like `.leading`, `.top`, etc should be working and are not.

> .accessibilityScrollAction(handler: (.leading))
>
> Type '(Edge) -> Void' has no member 'leading', mainView.swift, Error